# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, web, service, autowired

I am trying to write basic spring project. However, I have a big issue using `@Autowired through the Service. I didn't find the problem and got the error bellow:

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testeRS': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: br.com.lazycat.service.TesteServiceImpl br.com.lazycat.endpoint.TesteRS.testeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lazycat.service.TesteServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: br.com.lazycat.service.TesteServiceImpl br.com.lazycat.endpoint.TesteRS.testeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lazycat.service.TesteServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lazycat.service.TesteServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 31 more

mar 05, 2015 11:23:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet /lazycat threw load() exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [br.com.lazycat.service.TesteServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4969)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My AppConfig:

```
package br.com.lazycat.config;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"br.com.lazycat.repository"})
@ComponentScan({"br.com.lazycat.endpoint", "br.com.lazycat.config", "br.com.lazycat.service", "br.com.lazycat.model", "br.com.lazycat.repository"} )

public class AppConfig {

    private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
    private static final String DATABASE_USERNAME = "postgres";
    private static final String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "123qwe";

    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "true";
    private static final String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "br.com.lazycat.model";

    public static final String USER_CACHE = "userRestCache";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
           entityManagerFactory().getObject() );
          return transactionManager;
        /*HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;*/
    }
}
```

RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/teste", produces = "application/json")
public class TesteRS {

    @Autowired
    TesteServiceImpl testeService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/piroca/{nome}")
    private void testPut(@PathVariable("nome") String nome) {
        testeService.save(nome);
    }
}
```

Service - Interface

```
public interface TesteService {

    public void save(String nome);

}
```

Service

```
@Service("testeService")
@Transactional
public class TesteServiceImpl implements TesteService {

    @Autowired
    TesteRepository testeRepository;

    public void save(String nome) {
        Teste tst = new Teste();
        tst.setName(nome);
        System.out.println(tst);
        testeRepository.save(tst);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TesteRepository extends JpaRepository<Teste, Integer>{ 

}
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the qualifier from `@Service`.  Change `@Service("testeService")` to simply `@Service`.
2. Do not inject `TesteServiceImpl` directly.  Change `@Autowired TesteServiceImpl testeService` to `@Autowired TesteService testeService`.

`@Service(<name>)` assigns `<name>` to the bean instance created by Spring.  This is not necessary unless you have multiple implementations of a component.  For example, if you had:

```
interface UserRepository {}
class UserLdapRepository implements UserRepository {}
class UserSamlRepository implements UserRepository {}
```

you would have two components in the Spring component registry that implement `UserRepository`.  Then, if you wanted to `@Autowired UserRepository userRepository`, there will be an ambiguity in which implementation of `UserRepository` should be autowired.  It is in this situation that `@Service(<name>)` would be useful.

When your class implements an interface, it is better to inject the interface instead of the class.  This becomes mandatory if Spring AOP is used with its default configuration.  In your case `@EnableTransactionManagement` triggers AOP that in its default configuration creates interface proxies.  Therefore, a `TesteService` (and not a `TesteServiceImpl`) proxy is created.  So, Spring rightly complains about there being no `TesteServiceImpl` instance when you try to inject it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the code, but the error persists

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me.  [Here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-injection) is your code with my changes.  Unit tests run with `mvn clean test` pass successfully.  Are you sure you do not have any other errors in your code?

Comment: Compare your code against the working solution, or post the smallest sample that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller. You generally autowire to your interface type and not impl.

```
public class TesteRS {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testeService")
    TesteService  testeService;
```